# Wordpress Gutenberg empty Page Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm relatively new to Gutenberg development. So forgive me if it's a silly question. I have a page in which a paragraph is always inserted by default. I'm assuming this is a template that can be edited and swapped out for a custom block or template?

[image]

Comment: You are correct. Swap with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes paragraph is often the default but clicking on the '+' button highlighted there, you could access the search bar and choose whichever type of block you'd like.

[Example of search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVmQF.png)

It's also possible to create reusable blocks by right clicking and saving it. Makes things faster.

[Creating reusable blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhBrx.jpg)

I found this helpful with learning WordPress.
[LinkedIn Learning WordPress Essential Training](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/wordpress-5-essential-training)

Hope that helps.